# Code running on debug mode but not on release mode

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, release

I'm trying to create a simple crossword puzzle game. Which I read a txt file that includes all information about the words(direction, starting position, clues etc.). I tried to debug and my program worked perfectly on debug mode even without any breakpoint. I use Code::Blocks 17.12. and GNU GCC Compiler. I'm a newbie on C so I couldn't figure out why my code doesn't work in release mode.

It crashes when I enter the name of txt file.

*sorry for long post but I don't know where the mistake is*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 10
#define MAX_CLUES_LENGTH 50
typedef struct
{
char *word;     //word and corresponding hint
char *clues;
int x;      //Starting x and y positions
int y;
char direction;     //H for horizontal, V for vertical
int f;      //solved or not
} Word_t;

Word_t* loadTextFile(FILE* myfile, int nrWords);
void displayBoard(int rows, int cols, char** myBoard);
int isBoardFilled(int rows, int cols, char** myBoard);
char** createArray(int rows, int cols);
int findIndex(int arr[], int size, int val);
void playGame(char** myBoard, int words, Word_t *rWords, int x, int y, int 
countToFinish);
char** updateBoard(char** myBoard, Word_t *nWords, int solve);

int main()
{
FILE *input_file;
char file_name[20];
int rows, cols, nrWords, count=0;
printf("\nEnter name of text file: ");
gets(file_name);
while(access( file_name, F_OK) == -1)
{
    printf("Cannot open the file or file does not exist.\nPlease try again: ");
    gets( file_name);
}
input_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
fscanf(input_file,"%d%d%d", &rows, &cols, &nrWords);
Word_t* words;
words=(Word_t*)malloc(sizeof(Word_t)*nrWords);
for(int i=0; i<nrWords; i++)
{
    words[i].word = malloc(sizeof(MAX_WORD_LENGTH));
    words[i].clues=malloc(sizeof(MAX_CLUES_LENGTH));
}
printf("Game is %d rows x %d cols with %d words\n", rows, cols, nrWords);
words=loadTextFile(input_file,nrWords);
char **myBoard=(char**)malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    myBoard[i]=(char*)malloc(cols * sizeof(char));
}
myBoard=createArray(rows,cols);
/*for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", myBoard[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}*/
for(int i=0; i<nrWords; i++)
{
    myBoard=updateBoard(myBoard, words, -1);
}
playGame(myBoard, nrWords, words, rows, cols, nrWords);

fclose(input_file);
free(words);

return 0;
}
Word_t* loadTextFile(FILE* myfile, int nrWords)
{
Word_t* temp;
temp=malloc(sizeof(Word_t)*nrWords);
for(int count=0; count<nrWords; count++)
{
    temp[count].word=malloc(MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    temp[count].clues=malloc(MAX_CLUES_LENGTH);
    fscanf(myfile," %c %d %d %s %[^\n]%*c", &temp[count].direction, &temp[count].x, &temp[count].y, temp[count].word, temp[count].clues);
}
printf("Words and clues are read!\n");
return temp;
}
char** createArray(int rows, int cols)
{
int count=0;
char** tempBoard = (char**)malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    tempBoard[i]=(char*)malloc(cols*sizeof(char*));
}
count=0;
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        tempBoard[i][j]='#';
return tempBoard;
}
void displayBoard(int rows, int cols, char** myBoard)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i<cols; i++)
{
    printf(" %d ", i+1);
}
printf("\n     ");
for(i=0; i<cols; i++)
{
    printf(" --");
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    printf("%d    |", i+1);
    for(int k=0; k<cols; k++)
    {
        printf("%-3c", myBoard[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("     ***************\n");
}
int isBoardFilled(int rows, int cols, char** myBoard)
{
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(int k=0; k<cols; k++)
    {
        if((myBoard[i][k])=='_')
            return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}
int findIndex(int arr[], int size, int val)
{
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==val)
        return 1;
}
return 0;
}
char** updateBoard(char** myBoard, Word_t *nWords, int solve)
{
if(solve==-1)
{
    for(int k=0; k<sizeof(Word_t); k++)
    {
        if(nWords[k].direction=='V')
        {
            int len=strlen(nWords[k].word);
            for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                myBoard[((nWords[k].x)-1)+i][(nWords[k].y)-1]='_';
            }
        }
        else if(nWords[k].direction=='H')
        {
            int len=strlen(nWords[k].word);
            for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                myBoard[(nWords[k].x)-1][((nWords[k].y)-1)+i]='_';
            }
        }
    }
}
else if(solve!=-1)
{
    if(nWords[solve].direction=='V')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            myBoard[((nWords[solve].x)-1)+i][(nWords[solve].y)-1]=nWords[solve].word[i];
        }
    }
    else if(nWords[solve].direction=='H')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            myBoard[(nWords[solve].x)-1][((nWords[solve].y)-1)+i]=nWords[solve].word[i];
        }
    }
}
return myBoard;
}
void playGame(char** myBoard, int words, Word_t *rWords, int x, int y, int countToFinish)
{
int gameOver=0;
char answer[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
int array[countToFinish];
int index;
int filled;
printf("\nCurrent puzzle:\n\n");
printf("     ");
for(int i=0; i<countToFinish; i++)
{
    myBoard=updateBoard(myBoard, rWords, -1);
}
displayBoard(x, y, myBoard);
while(gameOver<countToFinish || filled != 1)
{
    printf("\nAsk for hint:\n");
    printf("# Direction     row     col\n");
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    for(int k=0; k<countToFinish; k++)
    {
        if(rWords[k].direction=='H')
        {
            printf("%d: Horizontal    %d    %d\n", k+1, rWords[k].x, rWords[k].y);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d: Vertical      %d    %d\n", k+1, rWords[k].x, rWords[k].y);
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnter -1 to exit\n");
    printf("Which word to solve next?: ");
    scanf(" %d", &words);
    if(words == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    while(words>countToFinish || words<=0 )
    {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        printf("Please try again:");
        scanf("%d", &words);
    }
    index=findIndex(array, countToFinish, words);
    while(index == 1)
    {
        printf("That word has been solved before");
        printf("\nEnter -1 to exit\n");
        printf("Which word to solve next?: ");
        scanf(" %d", &words);
        index=findIndex(array, countToFinish, words);
    }
    printf("\nCurrent hint: %s", rWords[words-1].clues);
    printf("\nEnter your solution: ");
    scanf("%s", &answer);
    if(strcasecmp(answer,rWords[words-1].word)==0)
    {
        printf("\nCorrect!\n");
        gameOver++;
        myBoard=updateBoard(myBoard, rWords, (words-1));
        displayBoard(x, y, myBoard);
        array[words]=words;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nWRONG ANSWER\n");
        printf("Current puzzle:\n");
        displayBoard(x, y, myBoard);
    }
    filled = isBoardFilled(x, y, myBoard);
}

}
```

Comment: Your title already tells me you have **undefined behavior** in your code. UB doesn't mean guaranteed failure. But an optimizer fiddling with your code greatly increases the chance. I guess nobody will debug this wall of code for you, so get a debugger and learn to use it.

Comment: The title is hinting that you have an undefined behavior. But this is a huge code we are not going to debug for you.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Lol. Same idea, different wording.

Comment: @EugeneSh. indeed. btw, just looking at the first page, I spot a `gets()`. WTF? try [man gets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) it tells you **never use `gets()`** for a reason ...

Comment: And yes, if you indent your code properly, you increase your chance to spot the issue by about 30% for my estimation...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I will! I hate that C error thing. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Can you show us a data file too? And its name isn't longer than 20 characters, is it?

Comment: Have you tried turning on compiler warnings, like `-Wall` in gcc?

Comment: @hasan "*I hate that C error thing*" <- well, I can't speak for anybody, but I guess a great majority of "C fans" loves C because it lets you do whatever. And with great power comes great responsibility ;) A little less ironic: modern languages are typically completely defined. Something is correct or it is wrong. C doesn't work this way, if something is wrong, but can't be detected at compile time, it's just "undefined" -> anything can happen.